# Create hotkey to insert text

Tags: applescript, automator

I want to create a hotkey command that insert this text "/" in whatever application I'am

The reason is because I'm a developer and I use the / symbol a lot, the problem is with my keyboard layout, that symbol should be made with SHIFT + 7, and thats not easily done with one hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Keyboard Maestro**](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) can type text per hotkey:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) like this with KeyRemap4MacBook:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F1, KeyCode::KEY_7, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

You could also create ~/Library/KeyBindings/ and save a property list like this as DefaultKeyBinding.dict:

```
{
  "\Uf704" = (insertText:, "/"); // F1
}
```

It doesn't work in all applications though.

Answer (score 0):

you could use OS X´s built in correction to achieve something similar.

system settings -> keyboard -> text

then enter something (e.g. "!!!"), and that will automatically replaced by "/" in all cocoa apps.